# When I run the rake:db migrate command I get an error "Uninitialized constant CreateArticles"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, rails-migrations

I created a model ruby script/generate model Article (simple enuff)

Here is the migration file create_articles.rb:

```
def self.up
  create_table :articles do |t|
    t.column :user_id, :integer
    t.column :title, :string
    t.column :synopsis, :text, :limit => 1000
    t.column :body, :text, :limit => 20000
    t.column :published, :boolean, :default => false
    t.column :created_at, :datetime
    t.column :updated_at, :datetime
    t.column :published_at, :datetime
    t.column :category_id, :integer
  end

def self.down
  drop_table :articles
 end
end
```

When I run the rake:db migrate command I receive an error rake aborted! "Uninitialized constant CreateArticles."

Does anyone know why this error keeps happening?

Comment: What's the name of your migration file and what does your class declaration look like?

Comment: 20090106022023_create_articles.rb (migration file)
^ Wouldn't that be the same as above (class declaration)

Comment: Your class declaration should enclose all of the above and looks something like: class CreateMyModel < ActiveRecord::Migration

Comment: If the answer resolves the issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: To avoid this from happening, you can have Rails generate the migration file and Class name with one command: `rails g migration CreateArticles` and then keep the file and class name as is. This can be helpful with longer and/or more complex class names.

Answer (score 119):

Be sure that your file name and class name say the same thing(except the class name is camel cased).The contents of your migration file should look something like this, simplified them a bit too:

```
#20090106022023_create_articles.rb
class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration   
  def self.up
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, :category
      t.string :title
      t.text :synopsis, :limit => 1000
      t.text :body, :limit => 20000
      t.boolean :published, :default => false
      t.datetime :published_at
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :articles
  end
end
```

Comment: Sublime doesn't have a refactor.. nothing is perfect

Comment: Yep, that's the problem. Though I'm a little disappointed rails is so restrictive in this. Is there a way to override it so that the filename and the class name does not need to match? I feel bullied by the framework :-)

Answer (score 10):

It's possible to get the given error if your class names don't match inflections (like acronyms) from `config/initializers/inflections.rb`.

For example, if your inflections include:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'DOG'
end
```

then you might need to make sure the class in your migration is:

`class CreateDOGHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]`

rather than:

`class CreateDogHouses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]`

Not super common, but if you generate a migration or a model or something, and then add part of it to inflections afterwards it may happen. (The example here will cause `NameError: uninitialized constant CreateDOGHouses` if your class name is `CreateDogHouses`, at least with Rails 5.)

Answer (score 3):

If you're getting this error and it's NOT because of the migration file name, there is another possible solution.  Open the class directly in the migration like this:

```
class SomeClass < ActiveRecord::Base; end
```

It should now be possible to use `SomeClass` within the migration.

Answer (score 3):

The top answer solved for me. Just leaving this here in case it helps.

#### Example

If your migration file is called

```
20210213040840_add_first_initial_only_to_users.rb
```

then the class name in your migration file should be

```
AddFirstInitialOnlyToUsers
```

Note: if the class name doesn't match, it will error even if the difference is just a lower case `t` instead of an upper case 'T' in 'To' - so be careful of that!