# uninitialized constant in rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

So when running my rake task, I get back an uninitialized constant error, referring to one of my classes. Googling the error just points to a ton of results saying you need to add '=> :environment' onto the definition of your task, but I've already done that. Would the fact I'm using mongodb change anything? Here's my code:

```
namespace :db do
  task :betagen => :environment do
    key = BetaKey.create!(key: ARGV[0], limit: (ARGV[1] or -1))
    puts "Beta key '" + key.key + "' created."
  end
end
```

(the BetaKey is what's causing the error.)

Comment: What's the full error? (i.e. which constant is uninitialized?)

Comment: uninitialized constant BetaKey (as mentioned)

Comment: Is beta_key.rb in your app/models directory and is the class name capitalized the same way?

Comment: I have app/models/betakey.rb and it's capitalized as BetaKey. I'll go ahead and try with the underscore.

Comment: yeah that fixed it, thanks :P. I can accept an answer from you if you add one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I run the rake:db migrate command I get an error "Uninitialized constant CreateArticles"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413150/when-i-run-the-rakedb-migrate-command-i-get-an-error-uninitialized-constant-cr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(As per comment)

Make sure your class file is named `beta_key.rb` (with the underscore) if the class is camel-cased as `BetaKey`, since this is what the autoloader expects.